# One-to-many relationship and Fk-column location

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been working with one-to-many and many-to-one relations, and I found that the documentation differs between the sqlalchemy documentation and the flask-sqlalchemy documentation.

SqlAlchemy states that the `Relationship()` should be in the parent, and the `Fk-Column` in the child. Flask-Sqlalchemy states that it should both be in the child.

Flask-SqlAlchemy:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category',
        backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

SqlAlchemy:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

Which one is correct, and/or, what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct.  Neither SQLAlchemy nor Flask-SQLAlchemy outright state where a relationship goes, although their examples may favor one over the other.  The only difference is that the first example relationship has a [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.backref), so the relationship is accessible from both models, as opposed to the second example where only the Parent model has the relationship property.

In most cases, I add the relationship to the same model that has the foreign key, along with a backref so it's accessible from the related model.  You may only need the relationship on one side, so it's up to your specific use case when deciding what to do.  Another case is when you want to define the relationship explicitly on both models, using [`back_populates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) rather than `backref`.